# How to solve - ORA-00205

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to create a multitenant database, but I get ORA-00205

I made a directory for datafiles:

```
[oracle@localhost oradata]$ mkdir -p TESTCDB/data/TESTCDB
```

I made an initTESTCDB.ora file:

```
db_name='TESTCDB'
enable_pluggable_database=true
audit_trail='db'
control_files='/u01/app/oracle/oradata/TESTCDB/data/TESTCDB/control01.ctl'
db_block_size=8192
db_domain='' 
memory_target=629145600
memory_max_target=629145600
open_cursors=300
processes=300 
remote_login_passwordfile='EXCLUSIVE'
undo_tablespace='UNDOTBS1'
```

I set environment variables

```
[petar.testDB ~] vi .profile_TESTCDB
#!/bin/sh
umask 022
ORACLE_SID=TESTCDB; export ORACLE_SID
ORACLE_HOME='/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2/db_1'; export ORACLE_HOME
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Now, I try to startup database in mount mode and I get this error:

```
SYS> startup mount
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area  297795584 bytes
Fixed Size          8791960 bytes
Variable Size         234883176 bytes
Database Buffers       50331648 bytes
Redo Buffers            3788800 bytes
ORA-00205: error in identifying control file, check alert log for more info
```

Thanks in advance.
Petar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Creating a Database with the CREATE DATABASE Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admin/creating-and-configuring-an-oracle-database.html#GUID-18B03451-5C74-4B53-A892-656C3E8A2556)

If you want to create a database like that, then follow the steps listed on the above link.

Your next step should be `Step 8: Start the Instance`.

You have not created your the database yet, you do not have a controlfile, so you can not mount it. Startup the instance with `nomount`, then create the database with `CREATE DATABASE`.